# Manually Apply TortoiseSVN Revision to server without SVN

Tags: svn

I would like to manually apply a TortoiseSVN revision to a server that doesn't have SVN installed. My test environment has SVN, but the production one does not, so I was hoping that TortoiseSVN has a way to checkout/download only the files that have been changed as part of a revision, but with all the empty directories so that I can paste the revision files into server root and the files will be placed in their right directories. I can obviously create this sort of "patch" manually, but a more efficient solution would be better.

SVN will soon be installed on the production server, but it's out of scope for this project.

Comment: So you're basically saying you have a folder such as `/path/to/my/file.txt' and you made a change to that file. Then, you want to take the change of just that file _and_ it's directory structure so that you can just copy and paste it in your production environment without you having to drill down into each directory and replace the file(s); correct? I'm fairly certain svn doesn't support backwards recursion checkout/export. If you wanted a folder with just _that_ folder's children, you could do that. However I don't think it's smart enough to figure that out.

Comment: I imagine this wouldn't be too difficult to write a PHP script that you could call `svn log -v`, parse for the `M/` character, then copy the path into a separate directory for you. Maybe that could work?